# Is it necessary to save everything in redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-toolkit. Everything it's ok, but now I'm facing an architecture problem.

I have an endpoint that I need to call in order to get some data so I can do a final call.

This final call response will be the one that I'll use in order to create and do some logic in order to dispatch and save in the store, so:

1- Should I do both calls in the same createAsyncThunk call and just return what I need?

2- this asyncthunk call will just handle the data, i dont really need it to save anything, based on those 2 calls, it will dispatch others actions. Where I should place this?

Answer (score 1):

I have async thunks that dispatch other async thunks, no problem.

1- Yes, although it might be harder to track which api failed

2- It's easier if this thunk lives with the others in my opinion

Example:

```js
const BASE = 'user';

// some other thunk in another file, ignore implementation
const saveInLocalStorageAC = createAsyncThunk()

const fetchUserAC = createAsyncThunk(`${BASE}/fetch`, async (email, { dispatch }) => {
  const id = await getIdFromEmail(email); // service
  await dispatch(saveInLocalStorageAC({ loggedInUser: { id, email } })); // thunk
  return id;
})

const slice = createSlice({
  name: BASE,
  initialState: someInitialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUserAC.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      // here is where I decide if I want to update the state or not
      state.data = action.payload // id
    })
  },
})

export default slice.reducer;
```

If you check the actions with some sort of logger you would see something like:

```
user/fetch/pending
storage/save/pending
storage/save/fulfilled
user/fetch/fulfilled
```